# Filter CGNAT IPs from Log

Tags: web-server, logging, ip, nat, isp

I want to identify heaavy users on a web API I would like to ignore CGNAT IPs . I looked at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6598  Is this mandatory or can an ISP use any given IP ?

Is there a List of IP Adresses used for CGNAT ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Some ISPs use addresses from the Private address ranges (`10.0.0.0/8`, `172,16.0.0.0/12`, or more rarely `192.168.0.0/16`), but IANA has set aside Shared address space (`100.64.0.0.0/10`) for CGN.

As a business, you will not see any CGN addresses, just like you will not see any home user Private addresses. ISPs use NAPT, just like a home user does, to hide multiple Private or Shared addresses behind public addresses that the ISPs own.

You really have no way to detect if a packet is originally sourced from a Private or Shared address because NAPT used by CGN replaces the original source address with a public address.

Answer (score 0):

The [Carrier-Grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT) (CGNAT) IP allocation is represented by the following CIDR address:

```
100.64.0.0/10
```

You can use that expression for your log filter.